# busted No test files found matching Lua pattern: spec

Tags: lua, luarocks, lua-busted

[my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSTeK.png)

the contents of the file 'hhh.lua' is the same as file 'btest_spec.lua' (see my directory)

when I run 'busted' (just use commond 'busted') ,it return an error:

```
0 successes / 0 failures / 1 error / 0 pending : 0.00003 seconds
Error → No test files found matching Lua pattern: _spec
```

when I run 'busted btest_spec.lua' , it success and return :

```
●●
2 successes / 0 failures / 0 errors / 0 pending : 0.003049 seconds
```

when I run 'busted *', it success and return :

```
●●●●
4 successes / 0 failures / 0 errors / 0 pending : 0.006815 seconds
```

so ,why busted fail to find file 'btest_spec.lua' when I run 'busted'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a break in the dependency "penlight", which busted relies on.

See here - https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/busted/issues/528

The fixed version of penlight (1.4.1) is now on luarocks, which should fix your issue if you update busted.

Comment: I have penlight 1.5.4-1 installed, so this must be yet another issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error (macOS Sierra, fish shell) and solved it by running `busted .` instead of just `busted`. Note the period indicating busted should look in the current working directory.

Comment: Also fixed the problem on Ubuntu (gnome-terminal).

Comment: This is the correct answer! I have 1.7.0-1 installed in OSX with zsh and was facing the same error. Running it as `$ busted .` works.